# where is the location of uploaded file in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to upload file by this code:

controller:

```
public function fileupload (Request $request)
{

  $file = $request->file('image');
  echo 'File Name: '.$file->getClientOriginalName();
  echo 'File Real Path: '.$file->getRealPath();
  $file->move('uploads', $file->getClientOriginalName());

}
```

view:

```
<html>
   <body>
      
      <?php
         echo Form::open(array('url' => '/fileupload','files'=>'true'));
         echo 'Select the file to upload';
         echo Form::file('image');
         echo Form::submit('Upload File');
         echo Form::close();
      ?>
   
   </body>
</html>
```

and after that I receive this message:

```
File Real Path: /private/var/folders/d0/b3zwsx7530l115k5rrj0zkx80000gn/T/phpdDRwaz
```

but I cant find my file. What is the path and how can I access it?

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the file path before uploading the file, so check the folder uploads which is present in the storage folder in root.

```
storage\app\uploads
```

Comment: there isnt uploads folder in store/app

Comment: @Nilthebabe you want to create a folder uploads inside the app folder.

Answer (score 0):

update some code in your project so that you can easily upload and find the file real parh

```
    $path = public_path('products/images/');
    File::makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0777, true, true);               
    $file = $request->file('image');
    $archivo = value(function() use ($file){
    $filename = str_random(10) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            return strtolower($filename);
        });

        $file->move($path, $archivo);
```

The Upload file is find inside your laravel **public/images** folder hope this will help you Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find out default file upload path (storage_path) from

**/config/filesystems.php**

You can change that as per your requirements.

Hope this helps you.